# how to replace the cursor i-bar over text

Tags: html

Whenever my cursor is over some text, I need it to remain as a pointer rather than switching to the 'i-bar' style.  I have tried setting the style of my td to for example cursor:pointer, or cursor:default, but it doesn't change.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 9. http://jsfiddle.net/HqHEz/ can you show some code?

Comment: It's worth asking, do you really want the 'pointer' (as is the default behaviour over hyperlinks) or do you mean the default sort-of 'pointy triangle cursor' (the default when not over any particular type of element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style="cursor: pointer;"` should work. Can you post your code here.
Also, check out some other options [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml)